# Leaflet map shows no markers for GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping

Following the example below I try to add an external GeoJSON to my Leaflet map, but its markers don't appear on the map. I use this file [GeoJson](https://gist.github.com/vassilaros/3791204ca226d5b236b4cd3106ef23cf). Any explanation?

https://maptimeboston.github.io/leaflet-intro/

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Cyprus map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ height: 100% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

  // initialize the map
  var map = L.map('map').setView([35.170582481889134, 33.42520000000002],9);

  // load a tile layer
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
      attribution: 'by <a href="http://www.acgoldman.com/">Goldman solutions & services</a>, Data by <a href="http://www.opencartography.com">Open Cartography</a>',
      maxZoom: 17,
      minZoom: 9
    }).addTo(map);

  // loading GeoJSON file - Here my html and PicnicSites.geojson file resides in same folder
  $.getJSON("PicnicSites.geojson",function(data){
    // L.geoJson function is used to parse geojson file and load on to map
    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error from console of Chrome:

[image]

```
$ is not defined
```

EDIT: The problem was the link of jquery and I didn't download any locally to.

Comment: What does the console output tell you? Every browser ships with developer tools. In Firefox you'd press `F12`, I'm not sure about Chrome, possibly `Ctrl + Shift + i`.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be helpful. PS.: Keep in mind that https://maptimeboston.github.io/leaflet-intro/ refers to Leaflet 1.0.3, but there is a small possibility that Leaflet 1.3.4 has a slightly different API. Always refer to the [latest documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson).

Comment: It looks like jquery isn't loading so the geojson can't be fetched. Try switching to a hosted version.

Comment: @MarcPfister you should post this as answer ;) I'm pretty sure this will solve his issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the console log shows, `jquery` is not loading. This means either your path is wrong, or you don't have it installed locally at all. Without `jquery` your code won't load the geojson file.

Easiest solution would be to just use a hosted version:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@2.2.4/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```